# LSTM for binary classification using multiple attributes

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, multivalue-database

I haven't used neural networks for many years, so excuse my ignorance.
I was wondering what is the most appropriate way to train a LSTM model based on my dataset.
I have 3 attributes as follows:

**Attribute 1**: small int e.g., [123, 321, ...]

**Attribute 2**: text sequence ['cgtaatta', 'ggcctaaat', ... ]

**Attribute 3**: text sequence ['ttga', 'gattcgtt', ... ]

**Class label**: binary [0, 1, ...]

The length of each sample's attributes (2 or 3) is arbitrary; therefore I do not want to use them as words rather as sequences (that's why I want to use RNN/LSTM models).

Is it possible to have more than one (sequence) inputs to the LSTM model (are there examples)? Or should I concatenate them into one e.g., input 1: ["123 cgtaatta ttga", 0]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concatonate the inputs into one, that part is done using the `tf.keras.layers.Flatten()` layer, which takes multiple inputs and and flattens them without affecting the batch size.

Read more here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Flatten

And here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#multi-step_dense

Not sure about most appropriate way since I wondered here looking for my own answers, but I do know you need to classify the data by providing some numerical identities to the text if applicable in your case.

Hope this helps